# AWS EB WSGI path refers to a file that doesn't exist

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app that I'm trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I'm getting the following error during the deployment:

```
2019-04-14 20:50:20    ERROR   Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.
```

I have updated the wsgi settings following [this guide](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/):

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    NumProcesses: '1'
    NumThreads: '15'
    StaticFiles: /static/=static/
    WSGIPath: Appname/wsgi.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: static/
```

The .ebextensions directory along with the elasticbeanstalk, the main django project folder (containing the settings and wsgi files) are all in the same directory:

```
.ebextensions
elasticbeanstalk
Appname
  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
```

***What could be causing the wsgi file to not be found?***

Comment: I'm guessing your folder isn't actually called `Appname`. Does its case exactly match what's in your YAML file? E.g., they're both exactly `Appname` or `AppName` or `appname`?

Comment: @Chris Yes, the casing matches both in the eb config and in the actual folder name. Maybe something else needs to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

You explained that the `Appname` directory contains this file

> - wsgy.py

Yet the config uses `i` rather than `y`:

```
    WSGIPath: Appname/wsgi.py
```